Story about giant insects occupying earth
I remember reading a (short?) story in which Earth was occupied by insectoid overlords, mostly larger than human-sized, but apparently somewhat modifiable.
This was probably some time in the 70s in a Danish translation.
The story centered around a female, insect-teacher, who was in charge of a group of young children. She had been modified to look almost human, like a beautiful woman; she had become strongly attached to the children.
Near the end of the story the occupying forces are leaving, and she is changed back to her original form; as far as I remember, she then commits suicide, making a large, temple (?) collapse over herself by emitting a very loud sound/song.
